# How to fix Xamarin Forms blank project build error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have some error in new Xamarin blank project.

I tried:

- Reopen VS
- Update all Nuget package
- Reinstall VS

The projet first build is failed with following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   Can not resolve reference: Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs, referenced by Xamarin.Essentials. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs, or remove the reference to Xamarin.Essentials. TestAPP.Android

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   Can not resolve reference: Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, referenced by Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, or remove the reference to Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout.    TestAPP.Android

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   The “Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.VerifyVersionsTask” task could not be loaded from the assembly…nuget\packages\xamarin.android.support.annotations\28.0.0.1\build\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly ‘…nuget\packages\xamarin.android.support.annotations\28.0.0.1\build\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.dll’ or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.   TestAPP.Android

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   Can not resolve reference: Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, referenced by Xamarin.Android.Support.CoordinaterLayout. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, or remove the reference to Xamarin.Android.Support.CoordinaterLayout.  TestAPP.Android

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   Can not resolve reference: Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, referenced by Xamarin.Android.Support.SlidingPaneLayout. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, or remove the reference to Xamarin.Android.Support.SlidingPaneLayout.  TestAPP.Android

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   Can not resolve reference: Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common, referenced by Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common, or remove the reference to Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.  TestAPP.Android

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   Can not resolve reference: Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common, referenced by Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common, or remove the reference to Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.  TestAPP.Android

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   Can not resolve reference: Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, referenced by Xamarin.Android.Support.SwipeRefreshLayout. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, or remove the reference to Xamarin.Android.Support.SwipeRefreshLayout.    TestAPP.Android

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   Can not resolve reference: Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, referenced by Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, or remove the reference to Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView.    TestAPP.Android

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   Can not resolve reference: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, referenced by Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, or remove the reference to Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.  TestAPP.Android
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't restored NuGet packages

Comment: Nothing changes after package restore.
Interesting, it works perfectly on another machine.

Comment: if this occurs for all new projects if you create a new project again ???

Comment: yes this error will occur for every new project without changing anything on it

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following

1. Upgrade all Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Essentials nuget packages across all the projects in your Xamarin.Forms solution
2. Close Visual Studio
3. Go into your Android project's .csproj file and change the version number for all the Xamarin.Android support nuget packages (probably something like v27.x.x.x) to the latest, which is v28.0.0.1 (just do a replace all to update to that version)
4. Delete your bin and obj folders from each project folder
5. Reopen the solution in Visual Studio, do a clean and rebuild

Comment: I tried, but not working.
My .csproj file it contains v28.0.0.1 basic